# My customer wanted to implement SSO on their ADFS environment and it shows them the below error. Is there any troubleshooting steps?

Tags: adfs

MSIS7007: The requested relying party trust 'https://domain/name/sso/saml' is unspecified or unsupported. If a relying party trust was specified, it is possible that you do not have permission to access the trust relying party. Contact your administrator for details.

Answer (score 2):

This means that either they have not configured the [SAML relying party](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/create-a-relying-party-trust) on ADFS or that they have but have not configured this endpoint.